# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'BTC' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently creating a website which consumes the CryptoCompare API, using VueJS. It consumes the API correctly (it shows the price of Bitcoin on the page), but I get errors saying:

```
"Cannot read property 'BTC' of undefined"
```

I have read other answers which state it is because the component on the page is rendered before the data is returned, but I cannot figure out how to solve this. I have tried to use `v-if`, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly, as it doesn't seem to work.

Is it also possible to just not render `price-container` until the data is returned?

HTML:

```
<div class="price-container">
   <p>
      <span class="price">{{ coins.DISPLAY.BTC.USD.PRICE }}</span>
   </p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
let CRYPTOCOMPARE_API_URI = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com";
let UPDATE_INTERVAL = 60 * 1000;

let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    coins: {}
  },

  methods: {
    getCoins: function() {
      let self = this;
      axios
        .get(
          CRYPTOCOMPARE_API_URI +
            "/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC,ETH,LTC,XRP,OMG,EOS,NEO,DASH,XMR&tsyms=USD"
        )
        .then(resp => {
          this.coins = resp.data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
        });
    }
  },

  created: function() {
    this.getCoins();
  }
});

setInterval(() => {
  app.getCoins();
}, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a `v-if` on the `span` element the error should go away.

The `if` should only check `coins.DISPLAY` as going further down the chain will generate the same error.

```
<span class="price" v-if="coins.DISPLAY">{{ coins.DISPLAY.BTC.USD.PRICE }}</span>
```

Here's a fiddle with a complete [example](https://jsfiddle.net/rjz82f1w/8/).

Comment: Thank you so much. I was using "coins.BTC", which obviously would not work!